# Yoneda Embedding into Left Exact Functors

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I think I am very confused about something.

I've been reading a bit about the Mitchell embedding theorem, and I read that the proof first embeds a given small abelian category $\mathscr{A}$ into the category of left exact functors $\mathcal{L}(\mathscr{A})$, $\mathscr{A}\to\text{Ab}$, via the Yoneda embedding.  Yoneda's lemma gives that this is fully faithful, and left exactness of Hom is meant to give left exactness of the embedding (which I believe), and apparently the hard part of the proof is to show that the embedding is right exact, i.e. the Yoneda embedding $\mathscr{A}\to\mathcal{L}(\mathscr{A})$ is exact.

But if this is the case, then doesn't that mean that if $0\to a'\to a\to a''\to 0$ is exact in $\mathscr{A}$ then $0\to h_{a''}\to h_{a}\to h_{a'}\to0$ is exact (h is Yoneda embedding here) and hence $0\to$Hom$(a'',b)\to$Hom$(a,b)\to$Hom$(a',b)\to 0$ is exact for for all $b$?  I guess not of course since Hom is not exact, so where am I getting tripped up?  Is this not a necessary condition of exactness in $\mathcal{L}(\mathscr{A})$?

Thanks.

Comment: You've implicitly assumed that evaluation at $b$ is exact, which need not be the case.

Comment: Thanks!  So exactness in the category of left exact functors does not imply exactness in Ab upon evaluation is what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: I know limits and colimits of set-valued functors are computed pointwise; I had never thought about this particular situation....

Comment: Okay, thanks again!

Comment: @Hurkyl You mean, limits and colimits in $[\mathcal{A}, \mathbf{Set}]$ can be computed pointwise. But anything can happen in a subcategory.